# How to send a message to a Discord webhook in node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, webhooks, node-fetch

I have tried the code posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804814/20635374) (with some modification), but it tells me that `fetch` is not a function.

```js
const fetch = import("node-fetch");
fetch(process.env.WEBHOOK, {
  'method': 'POST',
  'body': { 'username': json.username, "content": json.message}
}).then(res=> console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The error when using require:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
              ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/runner/chat/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /home/runner/chat/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /home/runner/chat/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js in /home/runner/chat/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/chat/index.js:15:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is enough information. What is process.env.WEBHOOK?

Comment: Also, if you need help with defining fetch(), you would have to post that as a separate question.

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty An environment variable containing my webhook????

Comment: Oops, I get it now. It's just the API link.

Comment: URLSearchParams() might be useful.

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty I'm not sure that's even related to what I am asking. This is Node.js, not static JavaScript.

Comment: It works in Node.js.

Comment: @SpeedoThreeSixty `URLSearchParams()` is for working with query strings in URLs, NOT making POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

`import()` is a function that returns a `Promise`, so you need to `await import('node-fetch')`.

You probably want

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

// Use this if you can't use import
// const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch(process.env.WEBHOOK, {
  'method': 'POST',
  'body': { 'username': json.username, "content": json.message}
}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Gives me this error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: + I already tried `require()`, but it tells me to use import instead.

Comment: What tells you to use import? What is the error?

Comment: You could do `import('node-fetch').then(...)` or `await import('node-fetch')` if inside an async block.

Comment: The console is telling me to import. I have edited my question with the error.

Comment: I can't use `.then()` because Ill use it later in the code when an event is called and my project isn't async.

Comment: @vlone you need to decide whether you are using ES6 modules or CommonJS modules. ES6 uses `import fetch from 'node-fetch'`, while the other uses `const fetch = require('node-fetch')`. This is outside the scope of this question but there are many solutions given that should work. You are given contradictory messages, one saying "cannot use import outside a module" and then "require in module not supported".

Comment: I use `require` with all the other modules and it works fine.

Comment: Those are just the errors, bud. I am not familiar with node so I don't know what they mean ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯